# What are the best Recovery softwares for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, gui, data-recovery

What are the best Recovery softwares for ubuntu 12.04?
Is there some of them that has a GUI?

What are the softwares that work with other file systems like fat.ntfs,hfs,...etc 
i need tools working on ubuntu to recover my lost/deleted files

Comment: This isn't really an **Ubuntu** issue.  Start with the **UBCD** .iso file (http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html), and report back on what you want to achieve *specifically* with Ubuntu ..

Comment: Have a look at [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/Version12-04)

Comment: I know its not ubuntu issue but all what i need tools working on ubuntu to recover my lost/deleted files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some paid recovery tools such as R-studio for linux  would be perfect

Comment: +1 for r-studio. And they also have a free version http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/Download.shtml

Comment: @blade19899 Thanks so much i like it. R-studio is perfect but i was searching for other tools to see other choices but it seems no choice to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try pmagic with is a small iso you can write on a usb key or cd and which contains many tools, it's all graphical as it uses kde and you can run clonezilla for backup.
This is what I use personnaly and it perfectly works, you can backup your system disc to another disc, another partition or to a server.

regards

[pmagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads)

Comment: It seems you misunderstand me what i need is recovery tools (tools that restore deleted or lost files) not backup tools and as you know pmagic contains backup tools and other that could help in recovery cases but they are not recovery tools.